MSAL JWT Token in session/localStorage and Token Cookie
I am working in the FE with React and BE with Hasura.
Since I am using azure for authentication I used the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) with msal.js and acquireTokenSilent for React.
According to the docs

Single-page application: Acquire a token to call an API
Acquire and cache tokens using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)

when using acquireTokenSilent the token is cached in the default storage which is the browser's sessionStorage.
From my understanding and what I read, storing tokens in the browser's storage is a security risk. Apparently, it is susceptible to XSS attacks.
I continued reading and I stumbled across to storing the token in the Cookie with the options httponly=True, secure=True, samesite='Strict'.
Here is a Hasura Action that is setting the token in the cookie of the FE from my BE service:
@set_token_api.route('/set_token', methods=['POST'])
def set_token():
    try:
        # return make_response("OK", 200)
        token = request.headers.get('Authorization', '').split(' ')[1]

        # Optionally, validate the JWT here if needed
        if not is_valid_token(token):
            return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid token', "status": "401"})

        response_data = {
            "message": f'Token set successfully {token}',
            "status": "200"
        }
        response = jsonify(response_data)

        response.set_cookie('jwt', token, httponly=True, secure=True, samesite='Strict')

        return response
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any unexpected errors
        return jsonify({'message': str(e), "status": "500"})

And here is the FE request triggering the setting of the cookie
fetch('/api/rest/set_token', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken, // Bearer token format
          },
        })

What confuses me is that now, I have the token in the sessionStorage or localStorage and in the Cookie.
From my understanding how I set up the token in the Cookie is safe from CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) attacks.
The accessToken in the POST request is being fetched via the acquireTokenSilent which is "saving" the token in the cache.
QUESTIONS:

Should I try to remove the accessToken from the browser's storage to avoid XSS attacks?
I still need to somehow provide a token for all the other requests to my BE. Would I then need to fetch the token every time from the cookie?

